# sparklyr hadoopConfiguration

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, sparklyr

I apologize that this question will be hard to make fully reproducible  because it involves a running spark context (referenced to as sc below), but I am trying to set a hadoopConfiguration in sparklyr, specifically for accessing swift/objectStore objects from RStudio sparklyr as a Spark object, but in general for a scala call to hadoopConfiguration. Something like (scala code):

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(f"fs.swift.service.$name.auth.url","https://identity.open.softlayer.com"/v3/auth/tokens")
```

where sc is a running spark context. In SparkR I can run (R code)

```
hConf = SparkR:::callJMethod(sc, "hadoopConfiguration") 
SparkR:::callJMethod(hConf, "set", paste("fs.swift.service.keystone.auth.url"), paste("https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3/auth/tokens",sep=""))
```

in sparklyr I have tried every incantation of this that I think of, but my best guess is (again R code)

```
sc %>% invoke("set", paste("fs.swift.service.keystone,auth.url"), paste("https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3/auth/tokens",sep=""))
```

but this results in the non-verbose error (and irregular spelling) of

```
Error in enc2utf8(value) : argumemt is not a character vector
```

of course I tried to encode the inputs in every way that I can think of (naturally enc2utf8(value) being the first, but many others including lists and as.character(as.list(...)) which appears to be a favorite for sparklyr coders). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have combed the source code for sparklyr and cannot find any mentions of hadoopConfiguration in the sparklyr github, so I am afraid that I missing something very basic in the core configuration. I have also tried to pass these configs in the config.yml in the spark_connect() core call, but while this is working in setting the "fs.swift.service.keystone.auth.url" as a sc$config$s.swift.service.keystone.auth.url setting, it is apparently failing to set these as a core hadoopConfiguration.

By the way, I am using Spark1.6, scala 2.10, R 3.2.1, and sparklyr_0.4.19.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out

```
set_swift_config <- function(sc){
  #get spark_context
  ctx <- spark_context(sc)

  #set the java spark context
  jsc <- invoke_static(
    sc,
    "org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext",
    "fromSparkContext",
    ctx
  )

  #set the swift configs:
  hconf <- jsc %>% invoke("hadoopConfiguration")
  hconf %>% invoke("set","fs.swift.service.keystone.auth.url",
                   "https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3/auth/tokens" )
}
```

which can be run with `set_swift_config(sc)`.

Comment: Good job. I would add to your code a `return(sc)` to be explicit even if it's not necessary.